# Receiver doesn't notice signal launch

Tags: python, django

I know this has been asked and answered before, but none of the proposed solutions has worked for me. This is my `signals.py`:

```
from django.dispatch import Signal

my_signal = Signal(providing_args=['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])
```

In the other hand, I have a file called `handlers.py` which looks like this:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from models import MyModels
from signals import my_signal

@receiver(my_signal, sender=MyModel)
def do_something(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'I'm doing nothing!!!'
```

I'm sending the signal in another file which looks like this:

```
from signals import my_signal
from models import MyModel

def some_function():
    my_signal.send(MyModel, arg1='a', arg2='b', arg3='c')
```

I don't know what to do. When I send the signal django doesn't complain, but the code in `do_something` function is never reached, is like the receiver wasn't working well or listening to the wrong kind of signal. Anyone?

Comment: Check order of your imports, logically it should be `signals.py`, `handlers.py` and then another file to send signal.

Comment: Maybe the issue is in __send(sender, **kwargs)__ sender shall be an instance of python class and not a python class prototype ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the solution!!! I noticed that `handlers.py` didn't had a generated `handlers.pyc`, which looked odd to me. So what I did was importing `handlers.py` in my `__init__.py` to tell django that this file exist and it worked perfectly. What I don't understand well is why. I believe it could be because that file wasn't directly referenced from anywhere in my code, just set as receiver of a signal but never explicitly called.

Answer (score 3):

When you define signals in django, you will need to register them. The best place to register it is in your `models.py`. To register your function `do_something`, move the code to the bottom of your `models.py` file:

```
.
.
@receiver(my_signal, sender=MyModel)
def do_something(sender, **kwargs):
    print 'I'm doing nothing!!!'
```

---

If you prefer to keep all your handlers in a separate file(`handlers.py`), you will need to import it in your `models.py` file.  Put this line of code at the bottom of your `models.py`:

```
.
.
from handlers.py import do_something
```

**Note:** Your must be careful with circular imports when registering handlers in a different file. This line can be harmful:

```
from models import MyModels
```

To still be able to get the model in your `handlers.py`, you can do this:

```
from django.db import get_model
my_model = get_model('<app_name>', '<model_name>')
```

Comment: That certainly should work, but I find another way of solving it without worrying about circular imports.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is likely not generating a .pyc because you have an syntactical error:

```
    print 'I'm doing nothing!!!'
```

If you are going to have a single quote inside your string, you need to mark the string with double quotes, or use an escape sequence.